# Show/Hide tab page from a combo box on a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, properties, controls

I have been looking around the internet for ages trying to find this solution to a problem i've been having.

I have a form (Form1) which consists of tabs and a subform (subForm1). Within subForm1 I have a combo box which I want to assign an AfterUpdate Event to. If the combo box (in the subform) is yes, show tab1, else if combo box is no then hide tab1. The code I'm looking for is something like this :

```
Private Sub Combo52_AfterUpdate()
If Me.Combo52.Value = "Yes" Then
Forms!FrmAssessment.TabCtl50.Pages(5).Visible = True
ElseIf Me.Combo52.Value = "No" Then
Forms!FrmAssessment.TabCtl50.Pages(5).Visible = False
End If
```

Got any ideas?

Comment: I've never worked with tabs, but I when I make something .enabled or .visible I usually add a .requery in the next line so 'Forms!FrmAssessment.TabCtl50.Pages(5).requery' can be added after 'Forms!FrmAssessment.TabCtl50.Pages(5).Visable = True' and the same for after 'Forms!FrmAssessment.TabCtl50.Pages(5).Visable = False'

Comment: Thanks for the comment, although I'm still getting the same problem. Getting error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method. :(

Comment: Maybe this is just a typo in your post, but if your code actually says `Visable`, it should be `Visible`.

Comment: Aw crap....I feel like such a dumbass....You were right Jeff! I just spelt it wrong....DOH!

Comment: Happens to the best of us :-)